# How to get sharepoint list data in cdata(xml) format

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2013, sharepoint-designer

i want to get sharepoint 2013 list data in cdata(xml) format using out of the box webpart.please suggest how to achieve it using OOTB webparts. sample code is attached here: 
 [Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mOkCF.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way to retrieve lists in xml is to use the default rss-button which will lead you to following page

_layouts/15/listfeed.aspx?List=your_listguid